# Can HTML5 MediaSource be used to dynamically generate a single-color video of arbitrary dimensions and length?

Tags: html, video, html5-video, media-source

Suppose I have a page that allows the user to choose a width, height, color and duration. I want the page to then generate a video of those dimensions and duration that's just a static frame of that color, that will then be played in a <video> tag on that page. Can I use the HTML5 MediaSource API to do this?

Eg: If the user chooses 704x396 + rgb(0, 0, 0) + 00:00:15, then I want to generate a <video> tag that plays a video that's 704x396 in size, 15 seconds long, and completely black. If you're familiar with [Aegisub's dummy video feature,](http://docs.aegisub.org/manual/Video#Dummy_video) that is basically what I'm trying to mimic.

From what I can tell, MediaSource only allows me to [feed raw video bytes in an actual video codec that the browser supports.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource/addSourceBuffer) It doesn't have any "higher level" API such as something that lets me feed individual frames.

If not MediaSource, is there any other way to do this (apart from bundling a webm / MP4 encoder compiled to JS of course) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `canvas.captureStream()` and `MediaRecoder`.

[HTMLCanvasElement-captureStream](http://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-fromelement/#widl-HTMLCanvasElement-captureStream-MediaStream-double-frameRate)

[MediaRecorder](http://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-record/MediaRecorder.html)

Works in Firefox currently. Will work in Chrome someday soon perhaps.

Comment: Ooh, didn't know you could do that with a canvas. I'll have to read up on these and experiment to see how it handles the video length / seeking.

Comment: Thanks, I got something working. I've posted it as an answer for other people's benefit, but I'll accept yours :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on Robert's answer, I have a solution that uses three things:

1. `canvas.captureStream()`, to get a stream of a canvas's contents.
2. `new MediaRecorder(stream)`, to convert that stream to a video format
   that a video element can use.
3. `MediaSource`

sideshowbarker's answer (now deleted) skips the MediaRecorder and directly assigns the stream as the video src. This /works/, but isn't suitable for my purpose because the video has dynamic, ever-increasing duration and cannot be seeked just like a stream. That's why I do need a MediaRecorder to record a chunk of video, and then repeat it over and over with MSE to reach the desired length.

An end-to-end sample of what I wanted to make is below. As Robert mentioned, it probably only works in FF at the moment. As of 2021-02, it works in FF 84 and does not work in Chromium 87.

```js
// @ts-check

"use strict";

/**
 * @typedef {{
 *     data: Blob,
 * }} BlobEvent
 *
 * @typedef {{
 *     state: "inactive" | "paused" | "recording";
 *     addEventListener(type: "dataavailable", listener: (event: BlobEvent) => void): void;
 *     pause(): void;
 *     resume(): void;
 *     start(timeslice: number): void;
 *     stop(): void;
 * }} MediaRecorder
 */

addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    /** @type {HTMLVideoElement} */
    const video = document.querySelector('#video');

    document.querySelector("#go").addEventListener("click", async () => {
        /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
        const colorInput = document.querySelector("#video-color");

        /** @type {HTMLSelectElement} */
        const resolutionInput = document.querySelector("#video-resolution");
        const [width, height] = resolutionInput.value.split("x");

        /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
        const durationInput = document.querySelector("#video-duration");

        await makeVideo(
            colorInput.value,
            [parseInt(width), parseInt(height)],
            parseInt(durationInput.value) * 60,
            video,
        );

        video.play();
    }, false);
}, false);

/**
 * Creates a video of the given color, dimensions and duration, and prepares the given video element to play it.
 *
 * @param {string} color
 * @param {[number, number]} dimensions
 * @param {number} duration
 * @param {HTMLVideoElement} video
 */
async function makeVideo(color, [width, height], duration, video) {
    video.width = width;
    video.height = height;

    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    /** @type {CanvasRenderingContext2D} */
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    /** @type {MediaStream} */
    const stream = canvas.captureStream(30);
    /** @type {MediaRecorder} */
    const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

    recorder.start(1); // Get as many events as possible to have a chance at getting the smallest possible chunk.

    requestAnimationFrame(function drawCanvas() {
        if (recorder.state === "inactive") {
            // recorder has stopped. No need to draw any more.
            return;
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(drawCanvas);

        // Frames aren't generated if the canvas isn't painted.
        //
        // Ref: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1277476
        context.fillRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    });

    /** @type {Promise<[MediaSource, SourceBuffer, ArrayBuffer]>} */
    const p = new Promise(resolve => {
        /** @type {Blob | null} */
        let blob = null;

        recorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", async event => {
            if (recorder.state === "inactive") {
                // Being called after recorder.stop(). Do nothing.
                return;
            }

            if (event.data.size === 0) {
                console.warn("No new data.");
                return;
            }

            recorder.pause(); // Don't get flooded with new blobs while parsing the current blob.

            if (blob === null) {
                blob = event.data;
            }
            else {
                blob = new Blob([blob, event.data], { type: blob.type });
            }

            // Data is available but may not contain any frames. Test for that.
            try {
                const [[mediaSource, sourceBuffer], buffer] = await Promise.all([newMediaSourceAndBuffer(video, blob.type), blobToArrayBuffer(blob)]);
                await appendBuffer(sourceBuffer, buffer);
                console.log(`Got enough data for ${ getEndTime(sourceBuffer) } seconds.`);

                resolve([mediaSource, sourceBuffer, buffer]);
                recorder.stop();
            }
            catch (ex) {
                console.warn(ex);
                console.warn("Waiting for more data...");

                recorder.resume();
            }
        });
    });

    const [mediaSource, sourceBuffer, buffer] = await p;
    await appendBufferUntil(sourceBuffer, buffer, duration);
    mediaSource.endOfStream();
}

/**
 * Sets up the given `video` to use a new MediaSource, and appends a new SourceBuffer of the given `type`.
 *
 * @param {HTMLVideoElement} video
 * @param {string} type
 * @returns {Promise<[MediaSource, SourceBuffer]>}
 */
function newMediaSourceAndBuffer(video, type) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const mediaSource = new MediaSource();

        function onSourceOpen() {
            mediaSource.removeEventListener("sourceopen", onSourceOpen, false);

            try {
                const sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(type);

                resolve([mediaSource, sourceBuffer]);
            }
            catch (ex) {
                reject(ex);
            }
        }

        mediaSource.addEventListener("sourceopen", onSourceOpen, false);

        video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
    });
}

/**
 * Converts a Blob to an ArrayBuffer
 *
 * @param {Blob} blob
 * @returns {Promise<ArrayBuffer>}
 */
function blobToArrayBuffer(blob) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.addEventListener("load", () => {
            resolve(fileReader.result);
        }, false);
        fileReader.addEventListener("error", event => {
            reject(event);
        });

        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
    });
}

/**
 * Appends the given video data `buffer` to the given `sourceBuffer`.
 *
 * @param {SourceBuffer} sourceBuffer
 * @param {ArrayBuffer} buffer
 * @returns {Promise<void>}
 */
function appendBuffer(sourceBuffer, buffer) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const currentEndTime = getEndTime(sourceBuffer);

        function onUpdateEnd() {
            sourceBuffer.removeEventListener("updateend", onUpdateEnd, false);

            if (sourceBuffer.buffered.length === 0) {
                reject(new Error(`buffer of length ${ buffer.byteLength } could not be appended to sourceBuffer. It's probably too small and doesn't contain any frames.`));
                return;
            }

            const newEndTime = getEndTime(sourceBuffer);
            if (newEndTime === currentEndTime) {
                reject(new Error("sourceBuffer is not increasing in size. Perhaps buffer is too small?"));
                return;
            }

            resolve();
        }

        sourceBuffer.addEventListener("updateend", onUpdateEnd, false);

        sourceBuffer.timestampOffset = currentEndTime;
        sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(buffer);
    });
}

/**
 * Repeatedly appends the given video data `buffer` to the given `sourceBuffer` until it is of `duration` length.
 *
 * @param {SourceBuffer} sourceBuffer
 * @param {ArrayBuffer} buffer
 * @param {number} duration
 * @returns {Promise<void>}
 */
async function appendBufferUntil(sourceBuffer, buffer, duration) {
    for (;;) {
        const currentEndTime = getEndTime(sourceBuffer);
        if (currentEndTime >= duration) {
            break;
        }

        await appendBuffer(sourceBuffer, buffer);
    }
}

/**
 * Gets the end time of a SourceBuffer.
 *
 * @param {SourceBuffer} sourceBuffer
 * @returns {number}
 */
function getEndTime(sourceBuffer) {
    return (sourceBuffer.buffered.length === 0) ? 0 : sourceBuffer.buffered.end(0);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label>Color: <input type="color" id="video-color" value="#2fa3fe"></input></label>
    <label>Resolution: 
        <select id="video-resolution">
            <option value="320x240" selected="selected">320 x 240</option>
            <option value="640x480">640 x 480</option>
            <option value="1280x720">1280 x 720</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <label>Duration: <input type="number" id="video-duration" value="25"></input> mins</label>
    <button type="button" id="go">Go</button>
</div>
<video id="video" controls="controls" loop="loop"></video>
```

Comment: Pretty cool—nice work. Please consider opening a PR to submit this to be included in the set of demos at https://github.com/mozdevs/mediarecorder (Though if you do it might also be nice to try to add some supplementary dynamic changing thingy to the HTML to give some indication of what’s going in behind the scenes.)

Comment: I've added controls to choose the color, resolution and duration to this snippet as well. I'll look into making that PR.

Comment: Cool, i looked for something like this also, however if throws a error: Error: buffer of length 1 could not be appended to sourceBuffer - do you have any fix?

Comment: @Endless I've updated the answer for 2021 and to point out that it works on FF 84 and not on Chromium 87. I see the warning (not an error, as you said) you're talking about on Chromium. It's supposed to be benign (which is why it's a warning; it happens on FF too) and eventually the MediaRecorder should yield more frames that *can* be appended to the SourceBuffer. For whatever reason Chromium does not do so. I did not investigate.